# SQL Server removing entries with duplicated information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a report identifying any customers using the same proof of identity as another customer.

After a series of other operations I have a table which has the name of a customer, the customers number, and the number of the proof of identity that they used when registering, grouped by the ID number, with any groups with only one entry left out.

The problem arises in that it seems a large number of customers have multiple accounts under their name and these need to be ignored, unless an additional customer also uses the same ID number, in which case all entries with that number need to be kept.

For example below, I want to remove entries 1-3 as it is clearly the same person, but retain both 4 and 5, because 6 does not match.

```
       ID # | Name    | customer number   
   1 | 1111 | April   | 321  
   2 | 1111 | April   | 432  
   3 | 1111 | April   | 431  
   4 | 2222 | Bob     | 987  
   5 | 2222 | Bob     | 454  
   6 | 2222 | Charles | 159
```

Is there any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID,Name,[customer number]  
FROM dbo.Customer c1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Customer c2
    WHERE c2.ID = c1.ID 
    AND   c2.Name <> c1.Name
)
```

Note that this also will omit records with a unique id/name. If you want to include these you have to use another `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID,Name,[customer number]  
FROM dbo.Customer c1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Customer c2
    WHERE c2.ID = c1.ID 
    AND   c2.Name <> c1.Name
)
OR NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Customer c2
    WHERE c2.ID = c1.ID 
    AND   c2.[customer number] <> c1.[customer number]
)
```

(assuming that `[customer number]` is the identifier since you haven't shown the pk column-name)